# What is the 'order' of a perceptron

Tags: artificial-intelligence, perceptron, neural-network

A few simple marks for those who know the answer.

I'm doing revision for exams at the moment and one of the past questions is:

> What is meant by the *order* of a perceptron?

I can't find any information about this in my lecture notes, and even google seems at a loss.

My guess is that the order is the number of layers in a neural network, but this doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: It's pretty rude to vote to close a question without giving a reason why in the comments :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to evaluate the **order** or **cardinality** of a **multilayered NN** you should consider **just the number of inner layer** as input and output layer are not considered belonging to the cardinality of the NN topology. 
For example a NN with 2 inner layer has order=2.

The funniest thing is that more than one layer is, most of the times, unusefull neither for performance neither for training.

Answer (score 0):

Order of approximation in the learning algorithm. See orders of optimization algorithms.